# Search for the syntax to display an HTML link in an OpenLayers popup

Tags: openlayers-2, popup, xml, link

I use a code found on the site : http://www.untourenvelo.ch/Carte_Plein_Ecran.html . It uses the Api Openlayers 2.13.1 .

In the development of this website it is possible to display GPX data that are in XML format, for points of interest called Waypoints, when clicking on one of them appears in a popup window the name of the point.

In my use I would like to display an additional data which is included between `<desc>` tags and which includes a hypertext link allowing to reach either photos or an HTML page.

The display of this popup is processed in the file : "Carte_Plein_Ecran.js" : http://www.untourenvelo.ch/Carte_Plein_Ecran.js

```
function onFeatureSelect(event) {
        var feature = event.feature;
        // Since KML is user-generated, do naive protection against Javascript
        //var content = "<h4>"+feature.attributes.name + "</h4>" + feature.attributes.description;
        var content = feature.attributes.name;
        if (content.search("<script") != -1) {
            content = "Content contained Javascript! Escaped content below.<br />" + content.replace(/</g, "&lt;");
        }
        popup = new OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud("MyPopUp", 
                                 feature.geometry.getBounds().getCenterLonLat(),
                                 new OpenLayers.Size(100,100),
                                 content,
                                 null, 
                                 true, 
                                 onPopupClose);
        feature.popup = popup;
        map.addPopup(popup);
    }
```

The link in the XML file (GPX file):

`<a href="http://lien url vers le site web">Lien vers le site</a>`  between tags `desc`.

I can't publish the content of the XML file, it is truncated.

I replaced the tag `desc` by `description` and in the file : "Carte_Plein_Ecran.js, I modified this line

```
var content = feature.attributes.name + "<br />" + feature.attributes.description;
```

in the popup, I can't display the hyperlink.

If possible, what syntax changes should be made to display this link?

Excuse me for my translation errors, I am French.